# best way to convert float into varchar in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the correct output of this SQL query in SQL Server

```
DECLARE @dt float;
SET @dt = 12345678912345678912345678912345678912;
SELECT
    STR(@dt, 50)
```

Output is:

> ```
>         12345678912345680000000000000000000000
> ```

My question is What is the best way to convert float into varchar in sql server for the above value?

Comment: Why are you storing integer values in a float? And what could you possibly need values this large for?

Comment: @SeanLange suppose my value is 123456789123456789123456789123456789.12 then also got wrong result.

Comment: select cast(@myFloat as char(50));

Comment: Is that the output you're getting or the output you want?  Are you asking why it truncates the 20+ least significant digits?

Comment: `float(n)` has a maximum precision of 7 to 15 (depending on n) digits. Anything more than that is not stored by float, but just the exponent is. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173773.aspx).

Comment: @Drew your query output is '1.23457e+037                                      ' & this will convert into scientific value.

Comment: a typo in my answer - after using decimal, also use `CAST`, not `STR` since that will simply convert it to a float and thus lose precision.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal so what everyone is trying to tell you even though you assign the float value as 12345678912345678912345678912345678912 it immediately losses precision and becomes 1.23456789123457E+35 as scientific notation (SELECT your value as float shows this as result).  But if you stored it as DECIMAL(38,2) then it would maintain the precision you desire and simply casting will give you the same string as the number.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `FLOAT` to store anything with more precision than 15 digits or they will get rounded, as per MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-za/library/ms173773.aspx). Either use `DECIMAL(38)` to get better precision - of up to 38 and use `CAST` instead of `STR`. `STR` converts it to float then to string, thus defeating the purpose.

e.g.

```
DECLARE @dt DECIMAL(38);
SET @dt = 12345678912345678912345678912345678912;
SELECT
    CAST(@dt AS VARCHAR(50))
```

Answer (score 0):

Closest you can do is 38 digit decimal as it is, Can you check below, but still you will loose some digits if it is more than 38 digits

```
DECLARE @dt float;
declare @dt1 decimal(38,2)
SET @dt1 = convert(decimal(38,2),123456789123456789123456789123456789.12);

SELECT
    convert( varchar(100), @dt1)
```

Comment: It gives '123456789123456800000000000000000000.00' output & my client wants same output in varchar format '123456789123456789123456789123456789.12'

Comment: Which version of sql server you are using, i tested it in sql server 2016 before posting

Comment: on our live server we have sql server 2012, we can't update our live server right now.

Comment: I checked by changing the compatibility to sql server 2012 and it returns valid number upto 38 digits

Comment: This will not work reliably as the number gets converted to a float with maximum precision of 15 digits. You try to convert it to a decimal with 38 digits precision just after you already lost that precision in the float.

Comment: @Adwaenyth You are correct.. but somehow it is returning 38 digits in my server... need to check what i am doing different..

Comment: @KannanKandasamy One possibility: The query optimization of SQL server 2012 and later might notice you actually want a decimal and just store it in a decimal with a simple query like that - as the number already has exactly 38 digits, it will work with a decimal.

Comment: Yep, not sure, i am using sql server 2016 and for this query i altered my database to compatibility level to 110 which is sql server 2012..

Comment: Tested it on a (real) 2008 just now and it will cut off at the expected 15 digits.

Comment: SQL 2014 gives me '123456789123456800000000000000000000.00' so perhaps it is sql 2016 specific that is allowing for higher precision but I am not finding documentation on that.

Comment: Can you check numeric?  SELECT
  convert( varchar(100), convert(numeric(38),@dt))

Comment: Just noticing it is not getting 0000's instead it is getting different converted number 123456789123456784102659645885120512

Comment: Well anything beyond the guaranteed precision is meaningless. It could be all 9's or anything as you can't be sure as the required digits aren't stored.

Comment: Yep, i thing we need to process this in python as a dataframe which will provide enough precision :)

Comment: @KannanKandasamy numeric is same result '123456789123456800000000000000000000.00' as decimal which makes since because numeric and decimal are functionally equivalent. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx

Comment: Can you try updating to decimal(38,2) before storing into float?

Comment: Edited my answer as per my comment